# Disable button with jQuery -- IE9 problem

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a snippet of code that disables upload button until something is selected to be uploaded. I just noticed that it does not work in IE9 Beta. Do I need to iterate it somehow more for IE? Here's my code:

```
$("input:file").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $("input:submit").attr("disabled",false);
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

I modified my code to add an alert:

```
$("input:file").change(function(){
    alert("...");
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $("input:submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

In FF alert comes on and enables button, in IE alert is not triggered.

ONE MORE UPDATE:

The problem went ahead without code modification. In IE9 there's a new icon for "COMPATIBILITY VIEW" next to web address field. I clicked it to enable and then clicked again to disable and the issue went away. My guess, IE blocked jQuery somehow and cached it. By changing the compatibility settings I might've removed cached settings. WEIRD!

Comment: Do you know exactly which function call isn't doing what it's supposed to? e.g., does the `change` event never fire? Does `$(this).val()` never return a truthy value? etc.

Comment: When I select file, the button remains disabled.

Comment: $("input:submit").removeAttr("disabled") that should enable the element

Comment: The last IE9 beta build I tested was not firing form element change events until the element loses focus (take for instance radio buttons and checkboxes). Those events should have fired immediately on changing the checked status. This was a bug with IE9, not my JavaScript. Have you tried clicking elsewhere in your form to remove focus from the upload element to see if the change event fires after doing so?

Answer (score 3):

try using `$("input:submit").attr("disabled","disabled");` to disable and `$("input:submit").removeAttr("disabled")`

Answer (score 0):

There are browsers out there - obviously also IE9 - that don't allow you to access the value of a file input filed for security reasons.

Comment: Can I run some other check? onclick perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to disable or re-enable a control:

```
function handleControlDisplay(className, foundCount, checked) {



    var button = jQuery(className);



    if (foundCount > 0 && foundCount == checked) {

        // enable

        button.removeAttr("disabled");

    }

    else {

        // set the disabled attribute

        button.attr("disabled", "true");

    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed tutorial from my website showing how to do this: [jQuery disable button](http://www.revillwebdesign.com/jquery-disable-button/). In a nutshell the best way to disable a button using jQuery is using the following code:

```
$('.buttonElement').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //TO DISABLED
$('.buttonElement').removeAttr('disabled'); //TO ENABLE
```

Hope this helps someone out.